# Why does my custom beanstalk keep restarting?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to customize the default AMI of beanstalk, but everytime I get server restarts after some random time. I went so far as not to change anything, but nothing works.

I have tried the following:

- find the instance of running beanstalk, create AMI, modify the AMI of beanstalk-crashing
- create new instance with same AMI as on beanstalk, create AMI, modify configuration-crashing

I have tried both stopping the instance before creating AMI, and creating AMI of running instance.

Edit: I found the answer here: [Can't generate a working customized EC2 AMI from Amazon Beanstalk sample appl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042000/cant-generate-a-working-customized-ec2-ami-from-amazon-beanstalk-sample-appl)

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, place the health status page to point to a dummy, static .html file. Although not recommended, this will prevent the health checks from restarting the machine and you could make more inside inspection.

AWS captures into the S3 logs only the ones output via java.util.logging. It means all console logging is not transferred.

That said, make sure you define an private key in your environment config, so you could ssh to it easily and see its output (it changes - for Tomcat 7, it is at /opt/tomcat7. For tomcat6, it is under /usr/share/tomcat6)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what aldrinleal wrote (can't comment yet): In the past, I would often find a failed Healthcheck would also disable my site. By which I mean: If you have the health check on your actual app and that app threw an exception, you wouldn't actually get to see anything, the environment would just report a failed state. Only after I changed to a static file for the health check, did I manage to see the errors.

Now I obviously this is more a problem with a dev environment and you can always just pull the logs. But especially in the beginning as someone new to AWS/Beanstalk this helped me a lot.