# customize Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are deploying a java web application in Elastic Beanstalk. The Beanstalk by default provides Redhat instances with Tomcat7 & openjdk. But i want to customize the instances so that i can use Sunjdk.
 Followed the steps as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042000/cant-generate-a-working-customized-ec2-ami-from-amazon-beanstalk-sample-appl), I launched a new instance from EC2 & installed sun jdk, tomcat7 and created a custom AMI of the instance and provided its ID in Custom AMI id field in edit Environment configuration in BeanStalk. But my Environment Health status is changing to RED, and the application is not deployed. Can you please suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have done exactly what you want to do, and am happy to report that it works.  In my first attempts I encountered the same issue.  Make sure that you:

- Create your custom AMI from a running instance of Amazon's beanstalk AMI that you **manually launch from EC2, NOT one that was launched from starting your application through beanstalk**.  This is very important, as Flashing a beanstalk launched EC2 instance won't work!!
- install Sun's Java as per these instructions, to make sure all the environment and symbolic links are correct.   https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=251168#251168
- be patient, as I found for some reason Tomcat takes longer to spin up than with the default OpenJDK config.

If you still can't get it, make sure you check the logs in /opt/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out - I hit a mysterious VerifyException that was resolved by uploading a new .jar to the environment, and I also ran out of permgen space almost immediately, which was resolved by upping the values in the 'Container' configuration area of the beanstalk 'edit configuration'.

Comment: I think they key here is the first point: I have been getting stuck launching a beanstalk instance, customizing it then saving the AMI - That DOES NOT work!

Comment: Yes that is key.  Added some bolding to highlight.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit point 1? How do I manually launch a beanstalk instance from ec2? thanks!

Comment: @Gevorg you go into the EC2 area, then launch an instance from a beanstalk AMI (go into the 'community AMIs' area and search for Beanstalk - then find the one you want based on your desired environment)