# PostgreSQL for Django on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm reading conflicting reports about using PostgreSQL on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk for python (Django).

Some sources say it isn't possible: (http://www.forbes.com/sites/netapp/2012/08/20/amazon-cloud-elastic-beanstalk-paas-python/).  I've been through a dummy app setup, and it does seem that MySQL is the only option (amongst other ones that aren't Postgres).

However, I've found fragments around the place mentioning that it is possible - even if they're very light on detail.

I need to know the following:

1. Is it possible to run a PostgreSQL database with a Django app on Elastic Beanstalk?
2. If it's possible, is it worth the trouble?
3. If it's possible, how would you set it up?

Comment: Now it is possible: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/

Answer (score 5):

Postgre is now selectable from the AWS RDS configurations.  Validated through Elastic Beanstalk application setup 2014-01-27.

Comment: Could you please outline the general procedure to select Postgre? I wasn't able to find it; I was only able to find this procedure that seems more complicated than what you described: http://serverfault.com/questions/456336/how-to-configure-elastic-beanstalk-for-using-rails-with-postgres#

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to run a PostgreSQL database with a Django app on
>   Elastic Beanstalk?

Yes. The dummy app setup you mention refers to the use of an Amazon Relational Database Service. At the moment PostgreSQL is not available as an Amazon RDS, but you can configure your beanstalk AMI to act as a local PostgreSQL server or set up your own PostgreSQL RDS.

> If it's possible, is it worth the trouble?

This is really a question about whether it is worth using an RDS or going it alone, which boils down to questions of cost, effort, usage, required efficiency etc. It is very simple to switch database engines serving django so if you change your mind it is easy to switch set up.

> If it's possible, how would you set it up?

Essentially you need to customise your beanstalk AMI by installing a PostgreSQL database server on an Amazon linux EB backed AMI instance.

Advice / instructions regarding customising beanstalk AMIs are here:

http://blog.jetztgrad.net/2011/02/how-to-customize-an-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-instance/

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=219630&#219630

[Customizing an Elastic Beanstalk AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002445/customizing-an-elastic-beanstalk-ami?rq=1)