# Amazon AWS Beanstalk Custom AMI Problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy an application to AWS that requires some extra software installed on the server. To create the custom image, I followed the instructions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049431/customize-elastic-beanstalk-instances) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042000/cant-generate-a-working-customized-ec2-ami-from-amazon-beanstalk-sample-appl) to start an EC2 instance and install my software. I then created a snapshot before terminating the instance.

Now my question: How do get beanstalk to use my snapshot when creating an application? When I try to create an application, only the 7 basic AMIs are available for 'container type'.

Answer (score 1):

From personal expirence I can say that most documentation on elastic beanstalk customization is outdated. What about using of custom ami, you need to know the actual version of the elastic beanstalk anyway installs beanstalk scripts and performs configuration on new instance bootstrap, so if you use custom ami it also happens. Base on this I would recommend to use custom ami when you need to have some OS level customizations.

If you need to install some additional software or change something I would recommend to use approach described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Good example described here: 
http://www.hudku.com/blog/innocuous-looking-evil-devil/

Also you can find a lot of examples on github if you try to find keyword: .ebextentions

Answer (score 0):

Fire up your environment configuration, and then switch to the custom AMI you've registered, in the Environment Settings. If possible, save a Configuration Template for further usage.